# UIWebView not appearing - Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

my project won't show the web view no matter what code i try use. I even tried a youtube tutorial. I know this question has been asked many times but it doesn't make sense to me. I used this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmMF7hWrYZk

Heres my code

If you need more detail please ask me. I'm knew to objective c

ViewController.m

```
//  FirstViewController.m
//  Have Your Say
//
//  Created by Cormac on 11/1/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 MK Software Corporation. All rights reserved.
//

#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize webView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]; 
    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
    [webView loadRequest:requestURL];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
//
//  FirstViewController.h
//  Have Your Say
//
//  Created by Cormac on 11/1/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 MK Software Corporation. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;


@end
```

Comment: Is your `webview` nil?

Comment: did you connect you webView with outlet?

Comment: 99% you didn't connect with outlet... please show us screenshot of connecting  webview with OB...

Comment: Same problem!!!! Very very strange!

Comment: @FahimParkar i did connect and I still have the same problem. any suggestions please? Ill cry a river, why did I update xcode at all...

Comment: @onskulis : can u make sample project and give me link? i will check and let you know...

Comment: Very VERY strange.... I did create new xcode 6 project to upload, new xib and it works but when I do use new xib in my old xcode 4 or xcode 5 project it doenst work if I create new xibs.....Its sooo confusing. And xcode 4/5 projects are not mine I cannot upload em sorry.